# Use product entity field as filter in Views

Tags: commerce, views

I have a product (type: "lamp") with a text field called "power".
On the Product display node ("showcase") i also want to see a block made with Views. It must show three other products of the same type AND power value. So Views should get a field's value of product rendered on the same node.
I've tried a lot of modules, various relationships combinations, but still can't get a product's entity field value.
Please tell me, what modules do i need and where should i go step by step.
(here are the modules i've installed: References, Entity Reference, Field reference, Node Reference, Field collection)

Comment: If you mean "node page view" when you say "product display node" then I think that you are looking for arguments / contextual filters. In Drupal 7 and higher this is available without any additional modules. Have a look here for example: [Contextual filters](https://www.drupal.org/node/1578558)

Comment: I've tried to simplify the problem and make a new content type "**TestPage**" with one extra list text field "**myfield**". Then i've added a View block "**vblock**" in a content region. View's table must contain just one section: "**myfield**"'s value. View should just show page's "**myfield**" value. I can't accomplish even that simple goal(

Answer (score 0):

I recently [learned](https://drupalize.me/videos/overview-page-manager-series?p=1147) how to do this kind of thing.

You need [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) which comes as part of [Chaos Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) for d7, and [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels).

1. In Page Manager, enable and edit the path /node/%node
2. Set the selection criteria to node-type = showcase
3. Create a context based on the entity reference field, or if that doesn't work you might need the [Relation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation).
4. Create another context based on the power field (you might like to use a taxonomy for that)
5. Make a view that uses the context to choose the products to display
6. Back in page manager, under Content, use Panels to determine where and how you want node and the view to display.

Follow the first link ("learned") for a much more thorough tutorial.